# file->getMimeType() always returns application/octet-stream with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, mime-types, file-upload

my file form element is very simple:

```
$this->archivo = new Zend_Form_Element_File('archivo');
$this->archivo->setLabel('Archivo:')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setDestination(UPLOAD_PATH)
        ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
        ->addValidator('Size', false, MAX_FILE_SIZE)
        ->addValidator('Extension', false, Application_Form_Multimedia_SubirArchivo::EXTENSIONES_PERMITIDAS);
$this->addElement($this->archivo);
```

but, when uploading the file (uploads OK), I try to obtain the MIME type but for every file is the same:

```
$form->archivo->getMimeType()
```

It always returns *application/octet-stream*, no matter what kind of file I'm trying to upload.

Why is this happening, did I miss something in the way? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is that if neither the fileinfo or mime_magic extensions are available in your PHP installation, the underlying method you're using will fallback to a default mimetype:

```
if (empty($result[$key])) {
    $result[$key] = 'application/octet-stream';
}
```

Suggest you check the getMimeType() method within Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Abstract - where that snippet is from and called from within Zend_Form_Element_File::getMimeType() - for details, and then check what extensions you have installed and rectify appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

today Zend Framework is 1.11.10 and resolution of this issue is not backported from ZF2. here is [bug report](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10461).

[here is the patch](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/365/files). the idea of the patch is that in php5.3 mimefile is included with php and we don`t need anymore external file.

also, to make use of this fix you should add validator like this:

```
$upload->addValidator('IsImage', false, array('magicfile'=>false));
```

Comment: Good answer. My issue was certainly outdated ZF1 `Zend_Validate_File_MimeType`. Love deleting lines of code to fix an issue.

Answer (score 0):

An Octet-Stream is generally any file that must be opened in another application. See:

http://kb.iu.edu/data/agtj.html

> A MIME attachment with the content
>   type "application/octet-stream" is a
>   binary file. Typically, it will be an
>   application or a document that must be
>   opened in an application, such as a
>   spreadsheet or word processor. If the
>   attachment has a filename extension
>   associated with it, you may be able to
>   tell what kind of file it is. A .exe
>   extension, for example, indicates it
>   is a Windows or DOS program
>   (executable), while a file ending in
>   .doc is probably meant to be opened in
>   Microsoft Word.